# Int13 device un/recognized?

Tags: boot, bios

I am writing the OpROM(BIOS) for a specific SCSI controller. The BIOS works fine before it is plugged into an Intel server board S2600CW. A HDD is attached to the SCSI controller, and is scanned and recognized by the SCSI BIOS. But when the system boots into MS-DOS environment(through an USB thumb drive), the SCSI device is simply missing! Checking BIOS BDA 0:475h and only 1 device is there(the USB drive).

But if I press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter system BIOS setup after SCSI BIOS is complete, the scanned SCSI device is shown on the boot device selection menu!

I manage to preallocate an area in BIOS EBDA to record how the SCSI is called  by system BIOS and can't seem to find anything unusual. The SCSI BIOS BCV is called after init stage, then the int13 routine is called like 52 times, with various commands passed in, such as 08h, 41h, 48h and 42h, all completed without error.

I have written BIOS for another SCSI controller and that one works fine on the same Intel M/B.

I wonder if any int13 function is mistakenly implemented that makes Intel system BIOS unhappy?